# Higher quadratic residues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory

In $\mathbb{Z}_N$ the quadratic residue of a number is its class for the equivalence relation $p \sim q$ iff there exists $r\in \mathbb{Z}_N^*$ such that $p=qr^2$.

1. Is it possible to count the number of classes, at least for $N$ prime? (it seems that for $N$ prime there are always 3 classes but I don't know how to prove this). In this case is it possible to choose a canonical representative from each class?

We can generalize this for $\mathbb{Z}_N^k$ for $k\geq 2$ in this following way. We arrange the $k$ numbers $p_1,...,p_k\in \mathbb{Z}_N$ as the diagonal elements of a diagonal matrix $P$, and we declare that two such diagonal matrices $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent $P\sim Q$, if there exist $R,S \in GL(k,\mathbb{Z}_N)$ suche that $R^T P R= S^T Q S$.

2. Is it possible to characterize the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_N^k/\sim$, counting how many elements it contains, and eventually giving a canonical element for each class?

Comment: "quadratic residue" is a term in standard use.  $q$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod n$ if and only if $q$ is congruent to a perfect square $\pmod n$.  Are you using the term to mean something else?

Comment: The 2nd question is fun. For the 1st question, note that $a^2=b^2$ iff $a=\pm b$ so there are $(p-1)/2$ (non-zero) squares. Taking a non-square $c$ it means that $c a^2$ takes $(p-1)/2$ distinct values, so there is no room for additional classes beyond $0,1,c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this could be useful for somebody, I solved the second question. The answer is in the appendix C of this paper of mine https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.09549 .